# Why do I now have 1 autosave in a mission instead of 3?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I am playing on Classic difficulty, and where I used to have three Autosaves for a mission, I now only have one (i.e. the same file is rewritten each turn, so I can't go back a turn). Did this setting get changed after a game update, or might this be a bug? I did some googling, but didn't find anything.

(I have read about an issue where once you reach 100 saves, your saves are listed out of order, but this isn't the case, because the one autosave is at the top.)

EDIT:
To clarify, I am *not* playing Ironman. The game autosaves at the beginning of each turn, and I can go back and reload that game. My problem is that there is only 1 autosave (which gets rewritten each turn), rather than the 3 autosaves that were previously being utilized (so that I could reload up to 3 turns prior).

The reason I ask is because one autosave is not that useful in a mission; the game is saved at the beginning of my turn, right after one of my guys gets killed. With 2 or 3 autosaves, I can go back to the beginning of the previous turn, and hopefully avoid the doom.

Comment: Classic difficulty is meant specifically to prevent reloading saves.  You are limited to a single save file.  Or am I thinking of Ironman?

Comment: Are you sure you're not playing in Ironman mode?

Comment: Ironman is the one that only allows one save. Classic allows you to save scum as much as you like. (And honestly entire games can go awry because of a really bad turn)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I figured it out! Just deleted some of the oldest autosaves, and it started creating 3 per mission again! :D try it out!